# React Native, iOS 15, fetch: TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch

I'm having this problem with fetch in React Native (on iOS 15.4):

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at fetch.umd.js:535:18
    at JSTimers.js:214:18
    at _callTimer (JSTimers.js:112:7)
    at Object.callTimers (JSTimers.js:357:7)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:419:27)
    at MessageQueue.js:116:12
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:370:9)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:115:10)
    at debuggerWorker.js:69:58
```

...and I have seen many recommendations to modify the `ios/[APP_NAME]/Info.plist` file to allow HTTP requests. Unfortunately, none of them work for me. And I am not sure if I'm missing any steps or what's wrong.

So first, the domain is `api.localhost:84` and this is my current snippet of the configuration:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I have also tried many other variations, such as:

1. changing the domain to `api.localhost` or `api.localhost:84`,
2. adding `<key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key><string>TLSv1.1</string>`,
3. setting the Exception out of the `NSExceptionDomains` (to apply to every domain),
4. using `<key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/>`,
5. using `<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>`...

I think I tried every solution, that I have found on StackOverflow and none of them work. Every time I make a change, I also uninstall the app from the simulator and rebuild it. I have also found some advice to use the IP (instead of `localhost`), but it said that it applies to Android and I know, that `localhost` used to work for me on iOS. But one day it stopped working.

Is there any step that I'm missing? Or was there any change recently, which would require doing things differently?

I'm clueless... When I google the error, all the links are already purple. I even tried the second page of google results. Nothing works.

PS: This is my JS code:

```js
class ApiConnector {

    static async post(api, path, body) {

        try {
            let response = await fetch(api.baseUrl + path, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: this.getHeaders(api.app.state.auth),
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            });

            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {

                // Success
                return response.json();

            } else {
                api.app.alert('"' + path + '" responded with ' + response.status);
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            api.app.alert('Request error ('+e.message+').');
        }

        return false;
    }


    static getHeaders(auth: {login: string, password: string}): Headers {
        let headers = new Headers();

        if (auth.login && auth.password) {
            let base64 = require('base-64');
            headers.append(
                'Authorization',
                'Basic ' + base64.encode(auth.login+':'+auth.password)
            );
        }

        headers.append('Accept','application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

        return headers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @zarathoustra Unfortunately nothing universal. I made an API that I tested locally (via postman) and then deployed it to an HTTPS server. And it was working when the API was on a secure server. But nothing that worked locally... really frustrating.